# Find all vector system bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have vectors:
$x_{1} = (1,2,0,0)$
$x_{2} = (1,2,3,4)$
$x_{3} = (3,6,0,0)$

I need to find all bases of those vectors system. This exercise is from task book and the answer is:
$(x_{1}, x_{2})$ and $(x_{2}, x_{3})$

But after gaussian elimination of matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1  & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    1  & 2 & 3 &4 \\
    3&6&0&0 
\end{pmatrix} $$

I get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    2  & 0  \\
    2  & 3 
\end{pmatrix} $$

and its not $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ or $(x_{2}, x_{3})$

So what is the right answer?

Comment: It would help if you could show your process of getting that matrix. Gaussian elimination doesn't change the dimensions of the matrix, so there seems to be something wrong with your attempt.

Comment: Observe that $x_3 = 3x_1,$ so these vectors are linearly dependent, hence the span of $x_1,$ $x_2,$ and $x_3$ has dimension (at most) 2. Further, there are only $\binom 3 2 = 3$ possible combinations of two vectors from these three vectors, and we already know that the combination $\{x_1, x_3\}$ will not work. Is it clear that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent? What about $x_2$ and $x_3?$